# How can I determine the remaining element of a given class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have a list of buttons. Each button belongs to a class ".button". Each button visually appears in its selected state. Each button also has a styling class that associates it with its given function, i.e.; ".widget-1", ".widget-2", hence `<div class="button widget-1">` and so on. When a button is clicked, I perform: `$(this).addClass("selected")`

Note that I have an arbitrary number of buttons, and I never know exactly how many buttons I will have at any given time as the list is data-driven and sized and styled dynamically at runtime.

However, there is a case where condition must be met when *only one* button is left remaining un-ticked, i.e.; one button that does not have the ".selected" class added.

Consider the following code for illustrative purposes:

```
for (var n = 0; n < Math.round(Math.random() * 10); n++ ) {
    $('<button />').attr({class: 'button widget-' + n})
    .appendTo('body')
    .click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        // Am I the last .button without .selected class?
    });
}
```

This is trickier than it sounds: Realize that each button will not know it is last until another arbitrary button in its class has been ticked.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your click handler body with this block of code, which will check to see if there are any other buttons selected.

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
if( $('button.selected').length == 0) {
    alert("This is the last button");
}
```

If the size of the collection of buttons with class "selected" is zero after adding class selected to the clicked button, then you know it's the last one.

Now, your question is slightly vague in that it's not clear if you're intending to only count buttons with the class "button" on it ("Am I the last .button without .selected class") or whether you intend to count all button elements. If you only want to count buttons with the class "button", then you'd use:

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
if( $('button.button.selected').length == 0) {
    alert("This is the last button");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the ambiguity: Your second example is what I was looking for. I was able to get my condition to fire, but had to use a slight variation of your counsel, whereby: `if( $('.button.selected').length == $('.button').length - 1) {alert("I am last!");}` Thanks again tremendously, regardless...this nitpick has been bugging me for hours!

Comment: I'm  happy to be able to help. Good luck!